# Python : determine which Raspberry Pi Model it is running on (etc)?

Tags: python

Now we have so many models of Raspberry Pi and considering the official software works on all of them....is there a Python Library that gives information about the host itself ? In particular what model of Pi it is running on , whether there is a SenseHat (etc) attached ?

Is there a sort-of standard 'raspberry-admin' Python Package already built for this sort of thing ?

Comment: Related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/61701/19949

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment the contents of the pseudo file /proc/cpuinfo is read by various programs to determine the Pi model.  The revision field gives the needed information.

```
A revision < 4 is an early model B.
A revision < 16 is a model A or B.
A revision of 17 is a compute module.
A revision of 16 or > 17 has a 40 pin expansion header.
```

I give that list as from that you can work out which GPIO are available.  You can break it down further to identify the precise model and board revision.

For full information you will have to treat the revision number as a 26 bit binary number as follows

```
2 2  2  2 2 2  1 1 1 1  1 1 1 1  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0
5 4  3  2 1 0  9 8 7 6  5 4 3 2  1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4  3 2 1 0

W W  S  M M M  B B B B  P P P P  T T T T T T T T  R R R R

WW   warranty void if either bit is set

S    0=old (bits 0-22 are revision number) 1=new (following fields apply)

MMM  0=256 1=512 2=1024

BBBB 0=SONY 1=EGOMAN 2=EMBEST 3=UNKNOWN 4=EMBEST

PPPP 0=2835, 1=2836, 2=2837

TTTT 0=A 1=B 2=A+ 3=B+ 4=Pi2B 5=Alpha 6=Compute Module 7=unknown 8=Pi3B 9=Zero

RRRR PCB board revision
```

I am not aware of any standard for identifying if a HAT is fitted or what it might be.  That may be an oversight in the HAT standard.